# How to run and stop thread randomly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

Here is the situation:

My python code generates TRUE and FALSE conditions randomly. I want a thread to run until the condition keeps evaluated to TRUE and when condition is FALSE the thread must be stopped.
For e.g. For 5 seconds condition is TRUE and for those 5 seconds I want to keep thread running but as after 5 seconds condition is changed to FALSE I want to stop that thread immediately. Now suppose the FALSE condition is true for 6 seconds and then after 6 seconds the condition is changed to TRUE then I want to again start the thread and run for the time until the condition is TRUE and stop it as soon as the condition is changed to FALSE.

In short the conditions(TRUE and FALSE) are changed randomly and I want to run the thread for the time period until the condition is TRUE and stop as the condition is changed from TRUE to FALSE.

Note : I have used Daemon=True but it does complete the running thread first so the main program halts until the thread is completely executed.

Comment: What part of the problem do you actually need help with? Do you know how to evaluate the condition? Do you know how to pause (not "stop", because that means it's dead and can't be started again) the thread? What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? Or any code at all?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to simply pause and unpause a thread in python in this manner. However, here is a nice way to mimick this behavior:

```
import threading
import random
import time

condition = True

def threadFunc():
    while 1:
        if condition:
            # do something useful

thread = threading.Thread(target=threadFunc)
thread.start()

while 1:
    condition = random.randint(0,1)
    print(condition)
    time.sleep(1)
```

The `condition` variable is shared between the child and parent thread. In the child thread, "stuff" is only done when the condition is true. In the parent thread, the condition is randomly changing each second to either true or false.